# Output visual (ASCII) Debian dependency tree to terminal?

Tags: linux, debian, apt, aptitude

I'm not sure if this is more of a SuperUser or UnixLinux question, but I'll try here...

Recently, I found this:

[#710689 - aptitude: use unicode character in the trees - Debian Bug report logs](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=710689)

> It would be nice when aptitude would use unicode characters for the trees in the
>   dependency lists, e.g. instead of:
>
> ```
> --\ Depends (3)
>    --- libc-dev-bin (= 2.17-3)
>    --- libc6 (= 2.17-3)
>    --- linux-libc-dev
>  --\ Suggests (2)
>    --- glibc-doc (UNSATISFIED)
>    --\ manpages-dev
> ```
>
> ...

... and I thought - wow, I really like that ASCII-art tree output, wasn't aware that `aptitude` could do that! So, I start messing for an hour with `aptitude` command line switches - and I simply cannot get that output? So my initial question was - where does that output come from in the first place?!

After a while, I realized that on my system, `aptitude` ultimately symlinks to `/usr/bin/aptitude-curses`; and I finally realized that `aptitude` has a `curses` interface! `:/`

So, I finally run `aptitude` without any arguments - and so the `curses` interface starts, and I can see something like this:

[image: aptitude-curses-terminal]

... so quite obviously, those ASCII tree characters come from the curses interface.

So I was wondering - is there a Debian/apt tool, which will output such a "visual" ASCII tree - but with actual dependencies of packages?

I know about [debtree - Package dependency graphs](http://collab-maint.alioth.debian.org/debtree/) (also [software recommendation - How to visually display dependencies of a package? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261772/how-to-visually-display-dependencies-of-a-package)); but I'd rather have something in terminal, resembling a directory tree (rather than the "unordered" [in terms of node position] graphs from `debtree`, generated by `graphviz`'s `dot`).

I've also seen [Is there anything that will show dependencies visually, like a tree?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=200216), which recommends:

```
$ apt-rdepends aptitude
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
aptitude
  Depends: libapt-pkg4.10
  Depends: libboost-iostreams1.42.0 (>= 1.42.0-1)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  Depends: libcwidget3
  Depends: libept1
  Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1)
  Depends: libncursesw5 (>= 5.7+20100313)
  Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.0.2)
  Depends: libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.7.3)
  Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.5)
  Depends: libxapian22
libapt-pkg4.10
libboost-iostreams1.42.0
  Depends: libbz2-1.0
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.3.6-6~)
  Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1)
  Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.2.1)
  Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
...
```

... which is good, because it lists first the immediate dependencies of the required package; and then the dependencies of the first-level dependency packages, and so on - but it's not visualized as a tree (and actually, `aptitude`'s `curses` interface simply shows installed info when you expand dependency node; it does not expand to further dependencies).

So, the question is - is there a tool, that would produce a dependency tree graph with terminal characters - like, say, in the following pseudocode:

```
$ pseudo-deb-graph --show-package="aptitude"

aptitude
  --- Depends: libapt-pkg4.10
  --\ Depends: libboost-iostreams1.42.0 (>= 1.42.0-1)
     --- Depends: libbz2-1.0
     --- Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  --\ Depends: libc6 (>= 2.3.6-6~)
     --\ Depends: libc-bin (= 2.13-0ubuntu13)
        --- ...
     --\ Depends: libgcc1
        --- ...
     --\ Depends: tzdata
        --- ...
...
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**You can do it with bash script**

Source code: "apt-rdepends-tree"

https://gist.github.com/damphat/6214499

**Run**

```
# sudo apt-get install apt-rdepends
# save gist, above, as "apt-rdepends-tree"
# chmod +x apt-rdepends-tree
# ./apt-rdepends-tree gcc
```

**Output look like this:**

```
# ./apt-rdepends-tree gcc
├─ gcc
│    ├─ cpp (>= 4:4.7.2-1)
│    └─ gcc-4.7 (>= 4.7.2-1)
└─ package-a
     ├─ package-b
     └─ package-c
```